# Parser stop mid-parse

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc

I am completely out of ideas. I spend every free minute this day on this, but I am completely out of ideas.

This is my `Ocamlyacc` grammar:

```
input: /* empty */ { }
    | input stmt { }

stmt:
    extern { print_endline "Got an extern import" }
    | func  { print_endline "Got function definition" }
    | call  { print_endline "Got function call" }

extern:
    EXTERN proto { Extern $2 }  

func:
    DEF proto expr { Function ($2, $3) }

proto:
    IDENTIFIER LPAREN id_list RPAREN { print_endline "Got prototype definition"; Prototype ($1, $3) }

id_list:
    /* empty */ { [] }
    | IDENTIFIER { [$1] }
    | id_list COMMA IDENTIFIER { $3 :: $1 }

expr_list:
    /* empty */ { [] }
    | expr { [$1] }
    | expr_list COMMA expr { $3 :: $1 }

expr:
    call { $1 }
    | expr OP expr { Binary ($2, $1, $3) }
    | IDENTIFIER { Variable $1 }
    | NUMBER { Number $1 }
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN { $2 }

call:
    IDENTIFIER LPAREN expr_list RPAREN { Call ($1, $3) }
```

When I start parsing `def foo(a,b) a+b` it should tell me it got a function and a prototype declaration, according to debug messages. But instead, I only get the message on parsing the `proto` rule.

Further debug messages show that the parser comes as far as to the `a` of the expression `a+b` and then stops. No error message, nothing else. It just stops as if the entire text hat been parsed completely without meeting any of the rules in `stmt`.

There are no shift/reduce error or similar. The AST types are also not the problem. I have no idea any more, maybe someone else can help. Surely it is something obvious but I cannot see it.

**EDIT**: Lexer by popular demand:

```
{
    open Parser
}

rule token = parse
    | [' ' '\t' '\n'] { token lexbuf }
    | "def" { DEF }
    | "extern" { EXTERN }
    | "if" { IF }
    | "then" { THEN }
    | "else" { ELSE }
    | ['+' '-' '*' '/'] as c { OP c }
    | ['A'-'Z' 'a'-'z'] ['A'-'Z' 'a'-'z' '0'-'9' '_']* as id { IDENTIFIER id }
    | ['0'-'9']*'.'['0'-'9']+ as num { NUMBER (float_of_string num) }
    | '(' { LPAREN }
    | ')' { RPAREN }
    | ',' { COMMA }
    | '#' { comment lexbuf }
    | _ { raise Parsing.Parse_error }
    | eof { raise End_of_file }
and comment = parse
    | '\n' { token lexbuf }
    | _ { comment lexbuf }
```

Comment: looks pretty good. definitely nothing obvious. lexxer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First point: I hated you a bit for not giving a *compilable* source code. I had to reinvent the AST types, the `%token` declarations etc. to test your code.

The problem is a delicate interplay between the

```
| eof { raise End_of_file }
```

lexing rule, and your grammar.

Raising `Enf_of_file` on EOF in the lexer is a good idea if your grammar never naturally encounters the end of the file. For example, grammars that are naturally `\n`-terminated or `;;`-terminated will stop parsing at this point, and never get to the EOF token.

But your grammar isn't one of those. When the parser gets to `DEF proto expr .`, it asks for the next token to see if it weren't, by chance, and `OP`, so it calls the lexer, which finds `EOF`, and blows.

Here is my fix:

In lex.mll:

```
    | eof { EOF }
```

In parse.mly:
    %token EOF

```
%start stmt_eof
%type <Types.stmt> stmt_eof

[...]

stmt_eof: stmt EOF { $1 }
```

Finally, you should seriously consider [Menhir](http://cristal.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/) as a replacement for ocamlyacc. It does everything `ocamlyacc` does, only better, with clearer grammar files (eg. you wouldn't have to reinvent the `foo_list` nonterminal each time), better error messages, debugging features...

Comment: Thanks, I switched to `Menhir` and replaced the `eof` rule. Also, thanks for helping me though you hate me.

Comment: @Scán: note that adding a different `stmt_eof` rules that ask for `EOF` after the `stmt` is generally a good idea: it makes sure that the grammar will only accept to parse the input if it can parse it *as a whole*. If you don't do that and have some bug in your grammar, it may happily return the longest prefix that it can parse, instead of alerting you of the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. Now my only problem is to make `ocamlbuild` find the `Llvm` module.